# jQuery Validate: compare two fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to check if value entered in one field is less than value entered in other field.

The Html:

```
<form id="bid_form_id">
    <input type="text" name="bid_price" id="bid_price_id" value="">
    <input type="text" name="bid_auto_decrement" id="bid_auto_decrement_id" value="">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $.validator.addMethod('le', function (value, element, param) {
            return this.optional(element) || value <= $(param).val();
        }, 'Invalid value');


        $('#bid_form_id').validate({
            errorElement: "small",
            rules: {
                bid_price:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            number: true

                        },
                bid_auto_decrement:
                        {
                            required: true,
                            number: true,
                            le: '#bid_price_id'
                        }
            },
            messages: {
                bid_auto_derement: {le: 'Must be less than bid price.'}
            }

        });
    });


</script>
```

The 'bid_auto_decrement' value should be less than the 'bid_price' value.
The script works for the first time. If I enter larger value in 2nd field, it shows 'invalid value' but after that if I enter correct values, it still shows error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The script works for the first time. If I enter larger value in 2nd field, it shows 'invalid value' but after that if I enter correct values, it still shows error.

This is because your custom rule is declared on `bid_auto_decrement`, which means your custom rule is only triggered by events on the `bid_auto_decrement` field.

Since you want to re-trigger validation on the `bid_auto_decrement` field whenever the value of `bid_price` is changed, then you'll need an event handler that programmatically triggers validation on the `bid_auto_decrement` field.

```
$('[name="bid_price"]').on('change blur keyup', function() {
    $('[name="bid_auto_decrement"]').valid(); // <- trigger a validation test
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/o7vgejsk/**

**Note**: you also misspelled the field name in your `messages` object as `bid_auto_derement`, so your custom message was ignored.

You also need to use `parseInt()` when evaluating or doing any math with the values of these fields, otherwise, they are considered to be strings.

```
$.validator.addMethod('le', function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value) <= parseInt($(param).val());
}, 'Invalid value');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. There is one strange problem though. Not sure why. The validation checks for first digit of the value. Try this - 1st value:100, 2nd value:10 (works). 1st value:100, 2nd value:20 (does not work) any suggestion?

Comment: @ShyamKadam, that's a problem within your custom method function.  You need to use `parseInt()` when evaluating or doing any math with the values of these fields, otherwise, they are considered to be strings.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code to add custom JQuery validation.

This will validate Max input and max input will always greater then Min input.

```
  <form id="menuItemTagsDetailsForm">

<div class="col-xs-12" id="item_tag_content_panel">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label" for="minimum_selection_for_bash_dish">* Minimum Selections</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control valid" id="minimum_selection_for_bash_dish" name="minimum_selection_for_bash_dish" required="" data-rule-required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <label id="minimum_selection_for_bash_dish-error" class="error" for="minimum_selection_for_bash_dish" style="display: none;"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label" for="max_selection_for_bash_dish">* Maximum Selections</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control error" id="max_selection_for_bash_dish" name="max_selection_for_bash_dish" required="" data-rule-required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
    <label id="minimum_selection_for_bash_dish-error" class="error" for="minimum_selection_for_bash_dish" style="display: none;"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" name="saveTagsSubmit" value="saveTagsSubmit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i><span class="hidden-xs">&nbsp;Save</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</form>
```

Add custom rules to your existing validation library

```
$.validator.addMethod('greaterThan', function (value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value) >= parseInt($(param).val());
}, 'Invalid value');
$("#menuItemTagsDetailsForm").validate({

     rules: {
       minimum_selection_for_bash_dish: {
           required: true,
           number: true

       },
       max_selection_for_bash_dish: {
           required: true,
           number: true,
           greaterThan: '#minimum_selection_for_bash_dish'
       }
   },
   messages: {
       max_selection_for_bash_dish: {
           greaterThan: 'Maximum selections is always geater then or equal to minimum selections.'
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$(function() {
    //Catch the forms submit event.
    $("FORM#bid_form_id").on("change", function(evt) {
        //Setup variables
        var valid = false;
        var max = $("#bid_price_id", this);
        var cur = $("#bid_auto_decrement_id", this);

        //Is the bid valid?
        valid = (parseInt(max.val()) > 0 && parseInt(max.val()) > parseInt(cur.val()) ? true : false);

        //If the bid is not valid...
        if ( !valid ) {
            //Stop the form from submitting
            evt.preventDefault();
            //Provide an error message (sorry for te use of alert!)
            alert("Oops!\n\nPlease make sure your bid is smaller than the previous.");
            //Focus on our textbox
            $("#bid_auto_decrement_id").focus();
        }

        //If the form is valid, it will submit as normal.
    });
});
```

While I appreciate that this is not using your jQuery validator, it shows the fundamentals of comparing two predictable values.

I hope this helps. I have not run this code.

Comment: This does help, though it gives alert even before entering anything in those fields.

Comment: As you acknowledge, this answer has absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.